# Erro "Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Preciso inserir uma API no meu site que traz a previsão do tempo para uma determinada cidade, porém, a requisição `ajax` sempre retorna o erro no console do navegador. Segue abaixo:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/tempo/json/são paulo-SP. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50745' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Segue o código da requisição:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/tempo/json/são paulo-SP',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(dados) {
             alert("Success");
        },
        error: function() {
             alert('Failed!');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Significa que falta o header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` que permite um site de dominio (ou porta) diferente ser acessado por outro(s).

- Leia mais sobre [CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/cors/info)

Se você tem controle sobre os scripts que rodam em `developers.agenciaideias.com.br`, será necessário adicionar tal header.

Se está usando c#, faça o seguinte:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Isto irá liberar pra todos domínios. Se quiser liberar para apenas um dominio especifico, supondo que o dominio que está o ajax seja algo como `https://exemplo.com` (e não seja https):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://foo.example");
```

Outra situação que vale ressaltar é o uso de urls não codificadas, recomendo que faça o seguinte no ajax:

```
url: 'http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/tempo/json/' + encodeURIComponent('são paulo-SP'),
```