# Desabilitar Access-Control-Allow-Origin no Chrome e Firefox

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic

Estou desenvolvendo uma app usando ionic no macbook com o OS X Yosemite.

Ao tentar enviar dados via POST ou receber via GET para um servidor remoto, aparece o erro:
**Chrome:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://elite-schedule.net/api/leaguedata/2009. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.13:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405

**Firefox:**

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://elite-schedule.net/api/leaguedata/2009. (Motivo: a requisição CORS falhou).

O código original era:

```
 function getLeagues(callback){

        $http.get('http://elite-schedule.net/api/leaguedata/2009')
          .success(function(data){
            callback(data);
          });
      }
```

E modifiquei para o seguinte, especificando o cabeçalho

```
 $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://elite-schedule.net/api/leaguedata/2009', 
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
        })
          .success(function(data){
            callback(data);
```

Já segui a orientação dada no site: [opensourehacker](https://opensourcehacker.com/2010/11/29/disabling-cross-domain-security-check-for-ajax-development-in-google-chrome/)

O erro persiste. Como desativar essas restrições nesses navegadores, usando esse sistema operacional?

Comment: Você não pode fazer isto no cliente `headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}`, o bloqueio/desbloqueio deve ser feito pelo servidor. Quem deve adicionar o header é o **elite-schedule.net**. Se você tem acesso a este site você mesmo pode adicionar isto. Se não você terá que entrar em contato com eles, ou então terá que criar um webProxy.

Comment: Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12363/3635, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78800/3635, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67617/3635

Answer (score 4):

Eu tive o mesmo problema que você.

O problema é de CORS, por padrão um servidor web só aceita requisições do mesmo servidor, provavelmente você está acessando de fora do seu servidor backend (mesmo estando na mesma máquina as aplicações devem estar no mesmo apache por exemplo).

Você precisa habilitar CORS no backend, no meu caso era um server backend node, segue o exemplo:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Request-Width, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 0):

Não se trata apenas de setar headers no backend.

O cliente-Web deve definir o que aceitar também.

Em ambiente de desenvolvimento, você pode contornar o problema (desabilitando as checagens de CORS no navegador) ou resolver o problema (definir as politicas de CORS no cliente e os headers no servidor).

Veja minha resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100263/8386